# Plotting mixing entropy

Tags: plotting

[image]Hello I am attempting to write a code for plotting mixing entropy. My graph will not show up. Please give guidance of how to fix my problem.

```
R = 8.145; n = 1 + ξ; 
Subscript[O, 3] = (1 - 2 ξ)/( 1 + ξ);
Subscript[O, 2] = (3 ξ)/(1 + ξ);
M[S_ξ _] := (-n R ((Subscript[O, 3] log Subscript[O, 3]) + 
                   (Subscript[O, 2] log Subscript[O, 2])));


Plot[{M[S, .1], M[S, .2], M[S, .3], M[S, .4], M[S, .5], M[S, .6], M[S, .7], M[S, .8]},
     {ξ, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with belisarius about there being "Too many errors in your code to point them out". So here goes.

Subscripted variables are fine for formatting symbolic mathematics in publications but not too good for doing computations. So I will start by rewriting your definitions in a form more amenable to computation.

```
R = 8.145;
n = 1 + ξ;
O3 = (1 - 2 ξ)/n;
O2 = (3 ξ)/n;
```

Nothing depends on `S`, so there is no reason to introduce it into `M`.

```
M[ξ_] = -(n R (O3 Log[O3] + O2 Log[O2])) // Simplify;
```

Note that the logarithm function is written `Log[...]` in *Mathematica*.

Because I want `M` to be reduced to its simplest form for efficient evaluation, I perform simplification of your expression for `M`. Because I want the simplification to be done only once, I use `Set` ( = ) not `SetDelayed` ( := ). This gives a nice, compact definition for `M`.

```
Definition[M]
```

> ```
> M[ξ_] = -8.145*((1 - 2*ξ)*Log[(1 - 2*ξ)/(1 + ξ)] + 3*ξ*Log[(3*ξ)/(1 + ξ)])
> ```

Befor plotting, I ask *Mathematica* to tell me what it knows about the domain of `M`.

```
FunctionDomain[M[ξ], ξ]
```

> ```
> 0 < ξ < 1/2
> ```

So there is no need to plot beyond 1/2.

```
Plot[M[ξ], {ξ, 0, .5}]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

Too many errors in your code to point them out

```
R = 8.145;
o[3, ξ_] := (1 - 2 ξ)/(1 + ξ);
o[2, ξ_] := 3 ξ/(1 + ξ)
M[ξ_] := -(1 + ξ) R (o[3, ξ ] Log@o[3, ξ ] + o[2, ξ ] Log@o[2, ξ ]);
Plot[M[ξ], {ξ, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]